# Get authorization code Box api in c#

Tags: c#, box-api, boxapiv2

I have a issue, I want get access a box with is code:

```
using (var request1 = new HttpRequestMessage() { RequestUri = new Uri("https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token"), Method = HttpMethod.Post })
        {
            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
            { 
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"), 
             //new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", boxAccessCode),
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", boxClientId),
             new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", boxClientSecret)

            }


            );
        }
```

but I don't know as can I get the "code", without into of the web
[http://127.0.0.1/?state=security_token%3DKnhMñlkjasdasnM0nHlZA&code=RCaBKsE681239OPyYLLWwutg9Nwmmk](http://127.0.0.1/?state=security_token%3DKnhM%C3%B1lkjasdasnM0nHlZA&code=RCaBKsE681239OPyYLLWwutg9Nwmmk)

How I can get this code by c#?

Answer (score 1):

There's good documentation on the OAuth2 flow in Box here:
https://box-content.readme.io/#oauth-2

The flow starts with navigating a browser/webview to the authentication page -- which should start with https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize. I'm not sure what the URL represents at the end of your question, but if it's the redirect url, loopback urls are generally discouraged.

In short, you must navigate to the authorize page with the appropriate parameters (eg. client id/secret, redirect url) once you successfully log in, box will redirect your webview to the provided redirect url where the auth code will be provided as a query string parameter. Using C# this will likely mean you will need to launch a webview of some sort.

There is a WPF example in the C# SDK that performs the entire OAuth flow:
https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2